# Prove of $m \equiv_4 n \rightarrow 123^m \equiv_{10} 33^n$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that, if $m \equiv_4 n$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $123^m \equiv_{10} 33^n$

I have no idea how to prove something like that

Comment: Well why do you want to prove that then?  If you are in over your head, back up and try some simpler problems.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $$\varphi(10)=4 \tag{1}$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Then, because 
$$123 \equiv 33 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 123^m \equiv 33^m \pmod{10} \tag{2}$$
But, it is given that $m \equiv n \pmod{4} \iff m=q\cdot4+n$, for some $q$. Because $\gcd(33,10)=1$, from [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_theorem)
$$33^{\varphi(10)}\equiv 1\pmod{10} \overset{(1)}{\iff} 33^4 \equiv 1\pmod{10}$$ or
$$33^{q\cdot4} \equiv 1^{q}\equiv 1\pmod{10} \Rightarrow 33^{q\cdot4+n} \equiv 33^{n}\pmod{10}$$
or 
$$33^m \equiv 33^n \pmod{10} \tag{3}$$
now, putting together $(2)$ and $(3)$
$$123^m \equiv 33^n \pmod{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The last digit of $3^1$ is $3$. The last digit of $3^2$ is $9$. The last digit of $3^3$ is $7$. The last digit of $3^4$ is $1$. The last digit of $3^5$ is $3$ again.

Answer (score 0):

$\bmod 10\!:\ \color{#c00}{3^{\large 4}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,3^{\large m}\! = 3^{\large n+4k}\!\equiv 3^{\large n}(\color{#c00}{3^{\large 4}})^{\large k}\!\equiv 3^{\large n}\ $ by [Congruence Product / Power Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)