# Prove that if $a \equiv_4 b$ then $3^a \equiv_{10} 3^b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. How can I prove that $a \equiv_4 b  \rightarrow 3^a \equiv_{10} 3^b$ with basic number theory?

Comment: have you tried Euler's theorem? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: It is very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975135/prove-of-m-equiv-4-n-rightarrow-123m-equiv-10-33n/)

Answer (score 2):

Note that from $$a \equiv b \mod (4) $$ we get $a=4k+b$

Thus $$3^a-3^b = 3^{4k+b}-3^b $$

$$=3^b ( 81^k-1)\equiv 0 \mod (10)$$

Comment: Thank you! But i don't see why $$3^b ( 81^k-1)\equiv_{10} 0  $$ holds ?

Comment: $81^k$ ends up with $1$ therefore $81^k-1$ ends up with $0$ which makes it a multiple of $10$

Answer (score 1):

Apply Euler's theorem. (notice that 3 and 10 are coprimes plus $\varphi(10)=4$.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $3^{4+n}=3^4\cdot3^n\equiv_{10}3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(10)=4$, so $x^4\equiv_{10}1\iff\gcd(x,10)=1$. Now, $a-b\equiv_4 0$, so $$3^{a-b}\equiv_{10}1\iff 3^a\equiv_{10}3^b$$